# Open web part properties panel with javascript

Tags: web-part, javascript, properties

I'm looking in a way to open the right side properties panel of my web part with javascript. This way when the user adds the web part to a page, a message and a button are displayed. Onclick the panel should open, like it does when clicking "Edit Web Part".

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration panel of the web part is called *Tool Pane* and you can open it using this simple JavaScript snippet :

```
lblErrorMessage.Text = "<a href=\"javascript:MSOTlPn_ShowToolPane2Wrapper('Edit', this,'" 
            + this.Parent.ID // Id of the current webpart
            + "')\">Edit Web Part</a>";
```

`this.Parent.ID` : return the WebPart ID that contain the UserControl